# Show a particular div until the content is loaded into another div in Phonegap web service

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova

I am doing a web service in Phonegap. The application fetches values from an XML file on a remote server when the user searches for a particular keyword, and loads the content to a div in my application. My problem is that I want to show a toast message like "loading..." or "progressing..." until the content is loaded into the div. I have created a toast message. But I don't know how to hide the toast message after the content is loaded since the time for fetching values from the XML file is different for different keywords.

The div to which the content is loaded is `<ul class="searchresults"></ul>`, and this is my toast function:

```
function toast(sMessage){
  var container = $(document.createElement("div"));
  container.addClass("loading");
  var message = $(document.createElement("div"));
  message.addClass("message");
  message.text(sMessage);
  message.appendTo(container);
  container.appendTo(document.body);
  container.delay(150).fadeIn("slow", function() {
    if ($(".searchresults").html().length > 0) {
      $(this).delay(500).fadeOut("slow", function() {
        $(this).remove();
      });
    }
  });
}
```

Can anyone suggest me some ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there a reason, why content loader will not be able to invoke function to dismiss the toast, when loading is complete?

Answer (score 1):

Create a JavaScript timer that tests the contents of your div, and hides the message when it finds something in there...

```
var myVar=setInterval(function(){myTimer()},1000);

function myTimer()
{
// test for content, hide message
}
```